# Firebase: User information in Authentication has security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Do firebase user information in Authentication has security rules to protect like we have in firestore?

Currently we protect the firestore collection with the below security rules.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /employees/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.admin == true || request.auth.uid == user
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

The write operations for the above collection are done by the firebase admin in firebase functions and hence I have blocked all write access from clients.

I am accessing the Authentication Users table through firebase admin sdk in firebase functions. I was wondering if there are security rules to enable and disable access from clients.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code what is your progress.

Comment: Firebase user auth object is only available to that user only. Firebase Admin sdk can read all the user's auth object.

Comment: Clarified. My take away here is, the user auth information can only be accessed through firebase-admin or the user himself and not accessible to other clients. hence no security rules are applicable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All access to Firestore via the Firebase Admin SDK (or any one of the other server SDKs) bypass security rules completely.  There is currently no way to simulate user access from the server SDKs either.  You will have to duplicate the logic of the security rules in your backend code.

If you would like to have security rules that work for backend code, you can always [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features), but I don't think it will be happening any time soon.  [Read this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips.html) for more information about the relationship between the admin SDK and security rules.